# How to expand a paper texture from a photo across a wider resolution than the original photo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

I have a photo that I'd like to turn into a wallpaper:

[image]

I'm pretty new to Photoshop, so I wasn't able to stack up the paper texture in a clean way. Is there a way to make this paper texture repeat in a non-obvious way to fill a 1920x1080 area?

**What I tried**

I have tried using some cleanup brushes but they didn't work the way I wanted them to.

[image]

Comment: Hi Preston Shumway, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work (Photos of what you tried always help)? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This is my first post, so I'm not used to the style of the site just yet. You've been incredibly helpful. How can I give you credit for your help?

Comment: There's a bit too much area to fill considering the amount of texture you have to work with and how the brightness is not uniform. It would help a bit if you could get a scan of that instead, but if you can get a scan of it you could probably also get a bigger sample of that texture, and you probably wouldn't be asking this question if that were the case. So, with that assumption, I think you might be better off cutting out the drawing and replacing the texture with something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Fill set to Content Aware and Color Adapt. It won't be perfect but it will work really well for this. If you want better I'd go back over it after to refine the texture a bit manually with either custom brushes or clone stamp.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! My verson wasn't _quite_ as clean as yours, but it looks pretty nice. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 7):

I'd just replace the background altogether. For this quick example I used the Magic Wand to make a selection of the background, inverted the selection, then applied a layer mask and put it on top of a re-colored [construction paper texture](http://www.photos-public-domain.com/2011/01/24/blue-construction-paper-texture/).

[image: Ghost wallpaper]